# Linux: write USB driver to force sending audio data over USB port

Tags: linux, drivers, usb, audio

I recently bought some Headsets, and for my great surprise they work through a jack 3.5 mm (source) to USB-C (dest) dongle. I can charge them using a USB (source) to the same USB-C (dest).
If I connect them (USB to USB-C) When I run `lsusb` I do not see the device recognized.
My question is: Is it possible (I'm not saying easy) to force to write data (audio) to the USB-2 port (source, laptop) and made the Headsets (connected in the endpoint) to sound (even random noise)?
Something like `cat /dev/random > /dev/path/to/usb-port`

Comment: I'd guess that the "some" headsets you bought are meant for a device that can use at least one particular USB port both as analog audio and as a real USB port. There's no way you can simulate that on another device that only has real USB ports. So if it doesn't show up as an USB device, you are out of luck. (And giving details about the "some" headsets might have helped to find which device that is).